# Passing Session to Body onLoad and Receive to another Page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need help!
So here is the scenario:
First, i will login to my page.
After logging in,there's a javascript function there called showDispatch(); which will load my another php file called _dispatch.php

Since i have a $_SESSION['username'], i want to pass it to _dispatch.php using the function of my javascript.
However,i can only do is put it on onLoad like this:

body onload="showDispatch('_dispatch.php');echo $user = $_SESSION['user']

What i want is to receive the session on my _dispatch.php.
Is it possible?Thanks!

I'm using php,html and javascript

Comment: once you store to the session, your other PHP pages will have access to them.  Jut put `session_start()` at the top of the page.

Comment: you don't need to pass it via javascript, it will be available in every other page that uses sessions

Comment: oh...thank you it is now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just only load your another page using your JavaScript code and retrieve your session variable.

On your **_dispatch.php** page:

```
session_start(); //start the session
$user = $_SESSION['username']; //retrieve session username
```